# Creating blank mpp file in Aspose.Tasks in C#

Tags: c#, ms-project, aspose

I want to create a balank mpp file in c# using Aspose.Tasks. Here is my code.

```
Project project = new Project();
project.StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 3, 3);
project.FinishDate = new DateTime(2015, 5, 6);
project.NewTasksAreManual = false;
project.CurrencyCode = "USD";
project.CurrencyDigits = 2;
project.CurrencySymbol = "$";
project.Save("D:\\DemoProject.xml", SaveFileFormat.XML);//Working
project.Save("D:\\DemoProject.MPP", SaveFileFormat.MPP);//Not working
```

I have a proper licence for Aspose.Tasks. When I try to save the file in mpp format I'm getting an exception **Project does not contain original MPP data. Only update of original MPP files is currently supported.**
But the same can be saved in xml format. 
Please lete me know how to create mpp file using Aspose.Tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current API, you cannot create an MPP from scratch. Only updating existing MPP is possible. Please refer to the [Aspose.Tasks documentation](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/tasksnet/Introducing+Aspose.Tasks+for+.NET) for details.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.